# $\Omega$-periodic modules in selfinjective algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Given a representation infinite (connected) selfinjective algebra $A$ with an indecomposable $\Omega$-periodic module $M$.

> Does $A$ then have infinitely many indecomposable $\Omega$-periodic modules?

Comment: Probably you already know this, but this is proved for weakly symmetric (connected) artin algebras in this paper of Auslander, Platzeck and Reiten: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404977900573

Comment: @JeremyRickard Thanks for the link, and of course the algebra is connected! I added it, thanks.